# Python: if/else inside a while loop problem multiple choice answer

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, option-type

I am new to python code someone please help me becasue it's important for my coding project.
I need help to solve my problem becasue i don't know what to do. For this code i would like for it to have the person who is running the code to choose his options and so it also print out the statments.

```
 powers = '1' or '2' or '3'
 while powers != '1' or '2' or '3':
    powers = input('Choose one of these numbers 1,2,3 to get your power ')
    if powers == 1:
        print('You have picked power 1 which increase your health by 40 ')
    elif powers == 2:
        print('You have picked power 2 which increase your strength by 40 ')
    elif powers == 3:
        print('You have picked power 3 which gives you a weapon ')
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Please make a clear problem statement

Comment: The duplicate's question is the "wrong way around", but the same principle applies - these kinds of comparisons just don't work that way.